# Why won't an an alert appear as called following a failed if statement?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to have an alert appear when the user's inputted password doesn't match their inputted password confirmation. Yet, when they don't match, the segue still occurs. Thanks

```
@IBAction func signUpAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if password.text != passwordConfirm.text {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Password Incorrect", message: "Please re-type password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){ (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
            }
            else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "when the user's inputted password doesn't match their inputted password confirmation" Where is your test for that?

Comment: debug the value of password and passwordConfirm. and share it. print something in the beginning of your function and test if it is running or not at all.

Comment: Remove the segue from the Button to the next ViewController. Then redo it, but from the initialViewController (not the button) to the next ViewController.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you hook the segue to the button , remove it and make it's source the vc itself ( drag it from the yellow rounded icon top of the vc in IB ) , as attaching the segue to the button will run it whatever the internal logic of the action

Comment: hmm, are you sure that logic cannot be run when a button even occurs? I'm new to coding but that seems unlikely

Comment: when the vc performs a segue , it can't present the alert at the same time , tried what i said ?

Comment: Agree with Khan, probably you set the segue from the button to the new view controller but you have to set it from view controller to view controller and use the identifier as you are doing now.